# Showing that an equation for radiation pressure from a star obeys the inverse square law and why this law breaks down near the surface.

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, inverse, mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

If the radiation pressure a distance $d>R$ from the center of an isotropic black body star is found to be $P_{rad}=\large{\frac{4\sigma T^4}{3c}}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{R^2}{d^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]$

a) How do I show that $P_{rad}$ obeys an inverse square law for $d>\!\!>R$?

b) Why does the inverse square law scaling break down close to the stars surface?

Comment: $1-(1-\epsilon)^{\frac{3}{2}} \approx 1 -(1 -\frac{3}{2}\epsilon) $

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the significance of that for me @KeithMcClary ?

Comment: It's the [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series) with $\epsilon = \frac{R^2}{d^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This procedure is used very often in physics in order to simplify calculations and make easier the physical interpretation when we have limited measurement accuracy or we don't need a high degree of accuracy (or we need to explain some point about conflicting theories)

First, consider the [series expansion of $(1-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20expansion%20of%20%281-x%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29)

$$(1-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}=1-\dfrac{3}{2}x^2+\dfrac{3}{2}x^4+\dfrac{1}{16}x^6+...$$

Now, if $0<x\approx 0$ we can approximate the LHS by $1-\dfrac{3}{2}x^2$ (we drop the square, the cube, etc. of a value almost zero)

Now, define $x=\dfrac{R}{d}$ and $W=\dfrac{4\sigma T^4}{3c}$

$$P_{rad}=W\left[1-\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]$$

But $R<\!\!<d$, then  $0<x\approx 0$ too. Then

$$P_{rad}\approx W\left[1-\left(1-\dfrac{3}{2}x^2\right)\right]=\dfrac{3WR^2}{2}\dfrac{1}{d^2}$$

Which is an inverse square law.

Finally, if we are considering points near the star, we have $R\approx d$, we have to include many terms from the series expansion and, as they depend on the inverse of the fourth, sixth, ... power of $d$, this obviously makes the formula very different from the simple one the inverse square law has.